# agg function to transform multiple rows to multiple columns with different type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to transform value of multiples row with same id into columns , but each columns is a different type.

Input data :

```
val dataInput = List(
  Row( "meta001","duration", 2 , null, null),
  Row("meta001","price", 300 , null , null),
  Row("meta001","name", null , null , "name"),
  Row("meta001","exist", null , true , null),
  Row("meta002","price", 400 , null,  null),
  Row("meta002","duration", 3 , null, null)
)

val schemaInput = new StructType()
  .add("id",StringType,true)
  .add("code",StringType,true)
  .add("integer value",IntegerType,true)
  .add("boolean value",BooleanType,true)
  .add("string value",StringType,true)

var dfInput = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dataInput),
  schemaInput
)

    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
    |     id|    code|integer value|boolean value|string value|
    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
    |meta001|duration|            2|         null|        null|
    |meta001|   price|          300|         null|        null|
    |meta001|    name|         null|         null|        name|
    |meta001|   exist|         null|         true|        null|
    |meta002|   price|          400|         null|        null|
    |meta002|duration|            3|         null|        null|
    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Expected output :

```
    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
    |     id|duration|price         |name        |exist       |
    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
    |meta001|       2|          300|         name|        true|
    |meta002|       3|          400|         null|        null|
    +-------+--------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I think i should use groupBy and pivot funtion but I am little bit lost when i should agg result :

```
dfInput.groupby("id").pivot("code",Seq("duration","price","name","exist").agg(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pivot here, just combine `first` with a `when`:

```
dfInput
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(
    first(when($"code" === "duration", $"integer value"), ignoreNulls = true).as("duration"),
    first(when($"code" === "price", $"integer value"), ignoreNulls = true).as("price"),
    first(when($"code" === "name", $"string value"), ignoreNulls = true).as("name"),
    first(when($"code" === "exist", $"boolean value"), ignoreNulls = true).as("exist")
  )
  .show()
```

gives

```
+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
|     id|duration|price|name|exist|
+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
|meta001|       2|  300|name| true|
|meta002|       3|  400|null| null|
+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `coalesce` function but all columns should be the same type, e.g "string".

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("code",Seq("duration","price","name","exist"))
  .agg(first(coalesce($"integer value".cast("string"), $"boolean value".cast("string"), $"string value".cast("string"))))
  .show()

+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
|     id|duration|price|name|exist|
+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
|meta001|       2|  300|name| true|
|meta002|       3|  400|null| null|
+-------+--------+-----+----+-----+
```

If you want to preserve the data type, then the function should be more complex, might need the conditional statements. Or just pivot to all and select the columns what you need.

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("code",Seq("duration","price","name","exist"))
  .agg(first($"integer value").as("int"), first($"boolean value").as("bool"), first($"string value").as("string"))
  .select("id", "duration_int", "price_int", "name_string", "exist_bool")
  .show()

+-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     id|duration_int|price_int|name_string|exist_bool|
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+
|meta001|           2|      300|       name|      true|
|meta002|           3|      400|       null|      null|
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration_int: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- price_int: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name_string: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exist_bool: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thats my problem, i want to preserve the data type.

Comment: I think you'd better to cast it again from the result.